# How can I get the size of a file using JavaScript (preferably using MooTools 1.2)?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, mootools, mootools1.2

How can I get the size of a file using JavaScript (preferably using MooTools 1.2)?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the size of a file provided to an `<input>` tag of type "file", or a file whose path your web application happens to know, well, you can't except in some very particular cases (like a page loaded from a "file://" URL).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the size of a file using JavaScript (preferably using MooTools 1.2)?

Local or remote?

If it's remote, I would do an HTTP HEAD request and check the Content-Length field.